# Returning subset using loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I wrote this code

```
function sub (str, start, end) {
    var newstr = ''
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if(i >= start && i < end) {
       newstr += str[i]
      }
    }
    return newstr
}
```

I expect the output of `('abcd',0,10)` to be 'ab', but the actual output is 'a'

Comment: You will get abcd not only a

Comment: You need this if: (i >= start && i <= end)

Comment: If start is 0 and end is 10, why would you expect only `ab`?  Wouldn't you have to call the function as `('abcd',0,2)`?  Also, why are you avoiding using the already existing `substr()` function?

Comment: can't use built-in functions

Comment: @stdob-- thanks a lot. that fixed the code

Comment: `"abcd".substr(0,2)` will yield `"ab"`

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to get a function which takes starting and ending index to return substring, then you can use `slice` function on Strings.

```
var word = 'ascsjdksjdnc';
word.slice(2, 4);
// Output: 'cs'
```